# How does HTML pagination work without a link or script?

Tags: javascript, python, html

Consider the following link:

https://www.officeworks.com.au/shop/officeworks/c/technology/monitors-digital-signage/27--monitors

The "View 100 per page" link does not change the url, nor does it have an onclick() attribute, yet it does reload the page and show up to 100 items. What variable has changed here, and how is it stored? Is it possible to get the HTML of the page with 100 items directly, without having to click the link or reload? Or get the page with 100 items programatically? (eg in Python)

Comment: Just because it doesn't have an onclick attribute in the HTML doesn't mean that there isn't an event handler assigned to that action.

Comment: You can use the browser's developer tools to see what Ajax requests are being made.

Answer (score 0):

One answer is the Ajax and Event system un Javascript.

You can have one HTML item like

```
<button id="but1">Show 100 items</button>
```

and add a **"click" event** on it from Javascript (example with **JQuery**)

```
$("#but1").click(function_but1_click);
```

This will launch the **function_but1_click()** function when the HTML button is clicked by the user.

After it, you can ask this function to perform an Ajax request to bring more data to the page (Example with JQuery)

```
function_but1_click()
{
    $.get('myDataLoader.php',function(data){
        items = JSON.parse(data)
        draw_my_items(items)
    });
}
```

And then implement the **draw_my_items()** function to display your new item on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The content is loaded dynamicly, an example of such feature is jQuery Ajax
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

There is no need to add a link, or onclick. You can bind event handlers to html tags / classes / IDs ...
https://api.jquery.com/click/

I think the storage happend on the server side, session side. Because i was not able to find a related cookie.

Good luck!